# How to retrieve data from DOM element and push it into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to loop through and retrieve attribute data bound in my select menu options and push the data from each option into an array.

My select menu has an id of "List" and the jquery code snippet below binds the value from the input field with id of ip4.

```
$('#List :selected').data({"onHandInv":$("#ip4").val()})
```

For each option in the select menu, List, there is a value of onHandInv that I would like to retrieve and push into an array.  I've tried the following for loop, but it isn't working.  Help please?

```
var Inv = [];
   for (j=0;j<document.getElementById("List").options.length;j++){
     Inv.push($("List option")[j]).valueof("onHandInv")  
    }
```

Comment: You need an hashtag here: `Inv.push($("#List option")...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery

```
var Inv = $.map($('#List option'), function(el) {
                return $(el).data('onhandinv');
          });
```

note that data attributes are always lowercase

In plain JS

```
var Inv     = [];
var options = document.getElementById("List").options;

for (var j=0; j < options.length; j++) {
    Inv.push( options[j].getAttribute('data-onHandInv') );
}
```

Note that `getAttribute` won't work for data set with jQuery's `data` method (neither will `valueof`), as it doesn't set attributes, it stores the data internally